# Handler is not getting invoked from a role in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to restart tomcat by invoking handler and that i need to invoke based on the condition of a variable. Somehow it's not getting invoked.

```
 - block:
    - debug:
        msg: "Configuration changes detected but no deployment, So proceeding with tomcat restart !!!!"
      notify:
        - Restart tomcat
    - meta: end_play
   when: config_var.changed  == true and myvm_release_version == current_release
```

I can see the message being displayed which means that the when condition is satisfying but after that handler is not invoked.

Output -

```
Sunday 31 May 2020  20:54:53 +0100 (0:00:00.084)       0:00:06.902 ************
  server1 ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Configuration changes detected but no deployment, So proceeding with tomcat restart !!!!"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that handlers are executed at the very end of the playbook unless they are explicitly flushed with [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html).

You can add a `meta` to `flush_handlers` if you need immediate handler execution.

Comment: Hi, That's what I want in this case. I want my handler to get executed and exit the play but it's not getting invoked as you can see above? I am not able to figure out why. Is it because the value of ```changed``` is coming as false?

Comment: I think I know the reason why. Handlers only triggers when their is a change in the task but since the value of changed is coming as false it's not invoking. **But when how do i invoke handlers based on the variables OR some condition?**

Comment: I am not sure you can trigger a handler based only on a variable change but what you can do is trigger the handle with the task that changes the variable. For example, in the task that you change the configuration for your tomcat, add a `notify` to trigger the Handler instead of having to deal with `config_var.changed`. Could you post the entire playbook maybe to check if what I said would work in your case?

Comment: Yes I think that's the issue. I added the notify in the task where the config is getting updated and it works. The thing is I have to only restart tomcat in the instance when there is only config change required and no code deployment and these 2 conditions are meeting using ```when: config_var.changed  == true and myvm_release_version == current_release```. Can i do something like add the 2nd condition in the handler task so that it will only trigger when the condition meets. Not sure if that will work though

Comment: You can set the other condition inside the handler:

```
handlers:
    - name: Restart tomcat
      debug: msg="I'm doing something"
      when: myvm_release_version == current_release
```

Comment: Also is there a way to end the play after this handler is invoked? Since it's just a config change so I don't want to proceed further and just restart the tomcat and end the play.

Comment: Then I think your original `- meta: end_play` should do the trick. You can place it as a task after the configuration file has changed or use the previous condition that you had `config_var.changed == true` to invoke it.